# Most Significant Digit Radix Sort in Java

Tags: java, radix-sort

I wrote the code for most significant radix sort but I keep getting an error of IndexBoundsException on the line: arr[i] = arr1.get(i);. And now I don't know what's wrong because the logic seems right to me.

```
  public static int[] msdRadixSort(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array is null!");
    }
    //search through to find msd
    int temp = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (Math.abs(temp) <= Math.abs(arr[i])) {
            temp = arr[i];
        }
    }
    //find the length of the msd
    int k = 1;
    while (!(temp / 10 == 0)) {
        temp = temp / 10;
        k++;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr1.add(arr[i]);
    }
    msdRadixSort(arr1, k);
    System.out.println(arr1);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr1.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? Show stack trace and show us the line causing it (since we cannot see line numbers). Also, have you tried *debugging* the code?

Comment: I have. I think the error occurs on the nested for loop: for (int j = 0; j < bucket.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bucket[i].size(); i++) {
            arr.add(i);
        }

Answer (score 1):

the nested loop is incorrect it should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < bucket.length; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bucket[j].size(); i++) {
        arr.add(bucket[j].get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't really fix the error. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I think the buckets are being put into the correct bucket.

Comment: What error are you getting because when I ran it with my test values I didn't get an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I'm getting an error in the recursive method on bucket[temp].add(i);, msdRadixSort(bucket[i], k - 1);, and on the non-recurive one: msdRadixSort(arr1, k);

Comment: Here are one of the tests: public void sort() {
        int[] unsortedArray = new int[] {54, 28, 58, 84, 20, 122, 85, 3};
        int[] sortedArray = new int[] {3, 20, 28, 54, 58, 84, 85, 122};
        assertArrayEquals(sortedArray, Sorting.msdRadixSort(unsortedArray));
    }

Comment: You are doing `arr.add(i)1` in the nested loop you should be doing `arr.add(bucket[j].get(i))`

Comment: Right. I fixed that. I also get an ArrayOutofBoundsException error. I believe it's from this line: bucket[temp].add(i);

Comment: I don't get that error when I run with the test data. Also is it possible you could include the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: public void h01MSDRadixSortRandomSequence() {
        expectedRadixSort();
        radixVals = Sorting.msdRadixSort(radixVals);
        assertArrayEquals(radixSorted, radixVals);
        //\u000AsuccessCounter++;
    }

Comment: private int[] radixVals = {776, 896, -171, 6, 228, -608, -696, 494, 659,
                               244, 506, -79, -544, 618, -145, 506, -935};

Comment: private Integer[] sorted = new Integer[vals.length];
    private int[] radixSorted = new int[radixVals.length];

Comment: When you divide `i` by `10^k` when `k` is 2 it gives you a value greater than 10.

Comment: So how should I fix it?